# Length of Specified Queue

Tags: java, queue

I am correcting one of my tests and I was completely incorrect on one question, as were many of the others in my class. Suppose we have the declaration:

```
ArrayBndQueue<String> q = new ArrayBndQueue<String>(10);
```

Choose one of the following to describe the length of the queue.

- A) The length is
- B) There is not enough information to compute the length of the queue
- C) This situation cannot happen

front = 8
rear = 7

We all thought that this was enough information for the queue. If the front is 8 and the back is 7, we thought it would be a full queue (of length 10). However, this answer was incorrect. Can someone explain why, exactly?

Comment: Without knowing the implementation of `ArrayBndQueue` it is impossible to answer the question.

Comment: Agreed with Jim. Collection classes have a size and a capacity. Not a length.

Comment: @JimGarrison - which is basically the answer to this question! You'd have made it an answer!:)

Comment: Right, that was the entire question.

Answer (score 0):

Queue is a Collection and so it has size() method which returns its size. It is unknown how ArrayBndQueue is implemented but all JDK Queues are empty after creation unless they accept another Collection as an argument at construction time.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information to compute the length of the queue absent any documentation or specification of `ArrayBndQueue`.

The part about 'front=8 rear=7' seems to be completely meaningless, as indeed is the entire question.